# how do I know if it is Windows server or unix?

Tags: unix, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003

how do I know on which platform is running my server: Unix or Windows server ?
I have only access to ftp, is there any php code to know it ?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have ftp access means you have the IP Address.

You would love to use [NMAP](http://nmap.org/).

[Example OS detection](http://nmap.org/book/osdetect-usage.html).

**PHP CODE**

> ```
> echo PHP_OS;
> ```

Try above code [here](http://writecodeonline.com/php/).

Source: [Predefined Constants](https://www.php.net/reserved.constants)

Answer (score 1):

[`ftp_systype()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-systype.php) might be able to tell you to some (unknown) degree of accuracy.